# Office AddIn Excel custom function not run correct

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to implement Excel addin custom functions.

First, I refer this doc [Tutorial: Create custom functions in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows), after run this from VS Code, the custom function auto generated `add` did not show up when I type in Excel cell.

For the auto generated project, it contains command, taskpane and functions, and i found [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared JavaScript runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime), it seems I need to configure the shared runtime. After configuring the shared runtime by following this doc, I am able to see the `add` function in excel cell, but, it keeps `#BYSY!`, and return error below in webpack windows.
[image]

How can I run a custom functions in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Function can also run normally without shared runtime, switch to shared runtime may not help to resolve your first issue.

For the first issue: `the custom function auto generated add did not show up when I type in Excel cell.`, if the function name cannot show up, that means this function failed to register. One possible reason is the namespace conflict. You can try to change this namespace in the `manifest.xml`,

[image]

and rerun following command to see if it helps:

```
npm run build 
npm run start:desktop
```

For the second issue, I cannot repro the error in webpack window. If you can give me more details (e.g. excel version, repro video, logs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging)), maybe I can reporo and help to solve it.

Thanks,

Rundong

Comment: I followed your steps to change the `Functions.Namespace`, but it did not work with a new project, I have appended all the detail logs here [Office AddIn Excel custom function not run correct
#295](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions/issues/295#issuecomment-978729258). There is `Resource Download Error Details` in log file

Comment: It seems my issue is related with the webpack. After `webpack-dev-middleware` and then reload the addin, the custom function will work. If I have issue with `SharedRuntime`, will open a new ticket.

Comment: Glad to hear the good news!

Comment: After switching to shared runtime, the error happened, could you help to have a check [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121875/office-addin-fail-to-load-after-swtiching-to-sharedruntime)