# Office Addin fail to load after swtiching to sharedruntime

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, office-web-app

I followed [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared JavaScript runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) to configure shared runtime for excel addin.

But, it fail to load

Here is my `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>f9459a58-57de-4427-9db6-b90ef7a6eb6c</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Meekou.ExcelAddIn"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Write your own Excel functions in TypeScript."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
        <AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
            <Script>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
            </Script>
            <Page>
              <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
            </Page>
            <Metadata>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
            </Metadata>
            <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </AllFormFactors>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.js"/>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.json"/>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Page.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="Meekou"/>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Here is the error

```
Compiled with problems:X

Error:

[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\edward\Meekou\Meekou\Meekou.ExcelAddIn\src\taskpane\taskpane.ts(37,34)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'add'.



Error:

[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\edward\Meekou\Meekou\Meekou.ExcelAddIn\src\taskpane\taskpane.ts(38,34)
      TS2552: Cannot find name 'logMessage'. Did you mean 'onmessage'?



Error:

[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\edward\Meekou\Meekou\Meekou.ExcelAddIn\src\commands\commands.ts(38,34)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'add'.



Error:

[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\edward\Meekou\Meekou\Meekou.ExcelAddIn\src\commands\commands.ts(39,34)
      TS2552: Cannot find name 'logMessage'. Did you mean 'onmessage'?
```

Comment: The errors you are getting are from typescript, and seem to indicate that something in `commands.ts` and `taskpanes.ts` is referencing functions that are not defined. Can you post a minimal reproduction in a github repo?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. I solved it by changing instructions within webpack.config.js.

// ========= I changed this ========= \

```
<pre>
const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      <b>functions: "./src/functions/functions.ts",</b>
      taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
},
</pre>
```

// ============ With this ============= \

Everything has worked well when i changed the instruction order. Put "functions" after "taskpane".

```
<pre>
const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
      <b>functions: "./src/functions/functions.ts",</b>
},
</pre>
```

my webpack version is 5.74.0

Hope this will help you.

Regard

Answer (score -1):

I cannot repro your issue. Your manifest looks all right.

From top of my mind, the error message should be related to "CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin" (it would be called during `npm run build`).

Before compile ".ts" to ".js", the plugin "CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin" would add "associate" logic (`CustomFunctions.associate("ADD", add)`) to the input file (e.g. `src\functions\functions.ts`).

From the error message, I guess maybe "CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin" performed the above steps incorrectly in your side. You can try to [add "associate" logic manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-troubleshooting#my-functions-wont-load-associate-functions) to see if the issue is resolved.

You can also share the compiled file (`dist\function.js`), so that I can help to make a further check.

Thanks,

Rundong

Comment: If you use the yo office to generate the custom functions add-in and meet build failed about custom function. You can try to remove the `custom-functions-metadata-plugin` in `devDependencies` of file `package.json` and reinstall it. (e.g. `yarn add custom-functions-metadata-plugin --dev`). In this way `custom-functions-metadata-plugin` will be updated to the latest version.